# Fill in an html table

Tags: excel, vba

In the HTML below I need to change the "11" value using a macro in excel. How do I access this code using `IE.document`? This is a part of a big html table I have to fill. I believe I have to address it using jQuery122013385348015163778="73", where 73 is the "address" of a cell in the table, but I have no idea how to. `IE.document.getElementByid("namediv").Value = "the value I have to fill in"` doesn't work, "nameid" likewise, while reading all of the div of the table through a for loop works fine. Does anyone know how?

My HTML:

```
<div id="namediv" style="WORD-BREAK: break-all" jQuery122013385348015163778="73" value="11">11</div>
<input id="nameid" type="hidden" value="11"/>`

div id="namediv" style="WORD-BREAK: break-all" jQuery122013385348015163778="73" value="11"

input id="nameid" type="hidden" value="11"
```

[image: Image of my HTML]

Comment: I'm no expert here, or rather it's been many years since I battled VBA to web scrape, but I think `IE.Document.getElementById("namediv").innerText = "the value I have to fill in"` or possibly `innerHTML` property. Not sure `Value` would refer to on a document.element.

Comment: Many thanks JNevill I was able to address the cell using a for loop through all the divs of the table and modify the text using your innerText solution. Though when I save the document it comes back to the previous value, I believe you've solved my problem. Many many thanks!

Comment: Your "Save the document" sounds off. When you edit a DOM it's editing the version in the browser that was pulled down from the web server. If it's just local HTML that is being displayed in the IE then you would need to edit that HTML file directly or the server code that produces that HTML.

Comment: Yes I agree. After several attempts the solution I first thought was at hand it's actually not. Right now I'm filling all the cells in the table using mousemove and sendkeys and is quite a good solution, but I believe there must be a smarter way for this task. Though I'm starting to realize I have to look for a different language, maybe i'll try java. Thanks anyway JNevill for the great help, that solutions works fine for different sections of the program.

Comment: Any language you use will merely be monkeying with the DOM and not the underlying HTML or the server code that produced it, so there likely isn't any "Saving" or rather maybe you can save the DOM locally as an HTML file. Perhaps you just want to extract data from a web page and then do something to it?

Comment: Actually the extracting of the data is in another section of the page and I can do i while the filling of the cells in the table is in a different page. I usually write on the table based on the data extracted before. So this section up above  is a cell I have to fill but there are many many others with different numbers in stead of 73. My mouse move solution works but when they make changes on the page or the table is even a little different or whatever event I didn't take care of happens is bothersome. Maybe I'll try to find the javascript function which takes care of this task?